# How to Initiliazed a button in CollectionViewCell Arrary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am new in swift .I have CollectionView in side tableView.I took code from this [link](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-add-uicollectionview-inside-uitableviewcell-using-swift/).  .I have modified it by adding the new CollectionView xib file and attached the corresponding swift files to new xib file .  I have successfully initialised image and label in first TableView cell

```
struct Colors {
    var objectsArray = [
        TableViewCellModel(
            category: "ALL DEALS",
            headerButton: UIButton.init(),
            colors: [
                [CollectionViewCellModel(image: UIImage(named:"Rectangle1x.png")!, dicountAmountLabel: "30%", dicountLabel: "Discount", customerTypeLabel: "For All HBL Customers"),
                 CollectionViewCellModel(image: UIImage(named:"Rectangle2.png")!, dicountAmountLabel: "30%", dicountLabel: "Discount", customerTypeLabel: "For All HBL Customers")]
            ])
    
        ,
        TableViewCellModel(
            category: "CATEGORIES",
            colors: [
                // SubCategory #2.1
                [CollectionViewCellModelButton(collectionButton:UIButton.init()),
                CollectionViewCellModelButton(collectionButton:UIButton.init()),
                CollectionViewCellModelButton(collectionButton:UIButton.init()),
                CollectionViewCellModelButton(collectionButton:UIButton.init())]
            ])
    ]
}
```

Here is my UICollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit
    class CollectionViewCellButton: UICollectionViewCell {
        
        @IBOutlet var collectionButton: UIButton!
        
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }
    }
```

Here is my Model struct

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct CollectionViewCellModelButton {
    var collectionButton: UIButton!
}
```

How to initialise the button in second tableView Cell with name in CollectionViewCellModelButton?

Line `CollectionViewCellModelButton(collectionButton:UIButton.init())` is giving syntax error how to correct it ?
Error is

> Cannot convert value of type 'CollectionViewCellModelButton' to
> expected element type
> 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka
> 'CollectionViewCellModel')

Answer (score 0):

Your UICollectionViewCell already has a UIButton outlet which will be initialized when cell loads
Here is the modified model, which you can use

```
struct CollectionViewCellModelButton {
    var btnTitle: String
}

// Initialize your model like this
TableViewCellModel(category: "CATEGORIES", colors: [CollectionViewCellModelButton(btnTitle: "text"), CollectionViewCellModelButton(btnTitle: "text1")])
```

Edit: The error you are getting is because you are passing data type **CollectionViewCellModelButton** to a type which is expecting **CollectionViewCellModel**

To fix this issue, you can create a common protocol which you can conform to both your models

```
protocol CollectionViewModel {
}

struct CollectionViewCellModelButton: CollectionViewModel {
    var btnTitle: String
}

struct CollectionViewCellModel: CollectionViewModel {
    var titleLabel: String
}

// pass the protocol to colors
struct TableViewCellModel {
    var category: String
    var subcategory: [String]
    var colors: [[CollectionViewModel]]
}
```

Now passing **CollectionViewCellModelButton** won't give error

But you have to downcast your model while using it like this

```
// set title in button like this
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionviewcellid", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
   // downcast CollectionViewModel to CollectionViewCellModelButton type
   if let model = self.rowWithColors[indexPath.item] as? CollectionViewCellModelButton {
       cell.collectionButton.setTitle(model.title, for: .normal)
    }
     return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
  }
```

Similar downcasting should be done while using **CollectionViewCellModel** also

Comment: pleas tell me how add button in this code:   `TableViewCellModel(
            category: "CATEGORIES",
            colors: [
                [CollectionViewCellModelButton(collectionButton:UIButton__?_`what code need to be added in ? mark place

Comment: Please refer the edited answer!!

Comment: title is not Button it is 'Name Label' that had gray colour...see my code that i have changed. I have `CollectionViewCellModel` that is same as code in link with sight changes .I have add new  xib with cell and struct provided above in question. `CollectionViewCellModelButton ` that should add button in 2nd   tableView section using this code . `colors: [
                [CollectionViewCellModelButton(collectionButton:UIButton),                     //How to initialise button ?
                CollectionViewCellModelButton(collectionButton:UIButton(coder: “text”),
          ] `. correct it?

Comment: `CollectionViewCellModelButton(collectionButton:UIButton(coder: “text”)` is giving me syntax error correct it ?

Comment: The error is. "Cannot convert value of type 'CollectionViewCellModelButton' to expected element type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'CollectionViewCellModel')" ......look i have edited  my question

Comment: Code is still not working should I upload code on link .so that you can download and correct you answer ?

Comment: Here is google drive link download it…  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tD9bESqueONS9jx5FgbRnk2Wkj2bVNOQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The value color that is in your TableViewCellModel is of type **CollectionViewCellModel** i.e the dataType of variable color is **[CollectionViewCellModel]** and you are trying to pass data of type **CollectionViewCellModelButton**.